# The Help Center page titled "Our model" doesn't describe … our model

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, help-center

[The Help page whose title is "Our Model"](/help/stackexchange) (but whose URL slug is `/help/stackexchange`) is currently a random grab bag of policies, formatting help, and random questions.

I was hoping that a page with that title would cover central topics around how these sites work.

- Voting and feedback, and how these mechanisms are supposed to result in the promotion of high-quality content.
- Reputation and privileges, and how these facilities foster responsible participation and encourage user moderation.
- Close reasons and criteria for what's on-topic and well-defined, including the process of editing closed posts to hopefully get them reopened.
- Different sites in the network have different topics and sometimes different rules for what's acceptable and how to vote, ask, and/or answer.

I can see how the terms of service, code of conduct, and AI policy would *also* fit in this context, but they should hardly be the main course; and there needs to be a place for Markdown help, badges, and tag search - but is this really that place?

Comment: It's certainly not a standard use of the word they have there. Don't get me wrong it's a page full of useful stuff, but if I were looking for the many things there, I wouldn't even consider looking at that page for them because of the title.